# Error parsing config file when running jshint

Tags: jshint

I always get the following output when trying to run jshint:

```
C:\Users\foo\Source\
λ jshint -c .glados-jshintrc gulpfile.js
ERROR: Can't parse config file: .glados-jshintrc
Error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿
```

My jshint config file is quite trivial, I copied it directly from the jshint docs:

```
{
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "predef": [ "MY_GLOBAL" ]
}
```

Any ideas to be able to get this working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that the issue was caused by Visual Studio. When I created the jshint config file in VS, it created it as UTF-8 with a prefix BOM (byte order mark). This seemed to break the config file parser. To fix the issue, I visited the File menu:

```
File -> Advanced Save Options
```

And changed Encoding accordingly:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This fix was also necessary in NotePad++.In Notepad++, the Settings > Preferences > New Document > Encoding (on the right side of the New Document window) > (at the bottom) select the lowest radio button and then select "Windows=1252". After setting this setting, You will have to create a new .jshintrc file. I am not sure that the below encoding setting for Windows is the only correct solution, but it is working. (I found this issue was found while using 'grunt' , jshint, and the '.jshintrc' file.) Thanks, again.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2015, File > Save As > Click the arrow next to the save button and click "Save with Encoding". Select the option to overwrite then you should see the same window above.